# C: snprintf not accepting \n for GUI display. Need suggestions

Tags: c, linux, printf

I need to put the last valid character as NUL, `'\0'`.

There is a char array `char cursStr[128];`
My intention is: `cursStr [lastCharacter where ends] = '\0'`

Here is the code snippet of how, this array is getting populated:

```
snprintf(num_range, sizeof(num_range), "%d-%d", devIndex, devIndex+127);
snprintf(dev_range, sizeof(dev_range), "%s%d...%s%d", devices[devPointer].name, 1, devices[devPointer].name, 128);
sprintf(cursStr, "%-7s  %-25.50s  %c%-30.30s  %5Ld%11s\n",
            num_range, dev_range,' ', "Empty", (var64)0, "GPT");
```

The reason why i am doing this, is because by printing in the GUI it is showing some junk caracter at the end. But printing at console prints just fine.
I even tried to do a `memset` of 0 to this array, but it does not help.

This is how it is getting printed to GUI and console.

```
             if (cursLine) {
                    TVdisplayText(cursLine, cursStr, &usedLines); // GUI
                    cursLine += usedLines;
             } else {
                    printf("%s\n",cursStr); // console
             }
```

The GUI library used is TVision (Turbo Vision)

Comment: The `printf` family of functions (including `sprintf`) puts the terminator at the end for you. You probably have some other error in your code. Maybe it's the newline in the string that's the problem for you?

Comment: If I understand you correctly (and perhaps I do not)... you're ending up with a character which you cannot explain at the end, and rather than solve this problem you're trying to hide the fact that a problem exists? If I'm wrong, you might restate your question better. If I'm right, well, lets just hope I'm wrong.

Comment: The character is called NUL with one L, to avoid confusion with the pointer macro `NULL`. Fixed it for you.

Comment: My guess is that `num_range` and/or `dev_range` are too small. They need to be large enough for what you're printing plus the terminating `\0`. Just try to enlarge them.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: You are correct. The `\n` in the sprintf was the cause due to which the junk character was showing in GUI. May be you can put it in the answer so that i can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many GUI systems can not show special characters like newline correctly. Either don't add the newline in the `sprintf` call, or manually remove it:

```
/* Remove the last character from the string */
cursStr[strlen(cursStr) - 1] = '\0';
```

Comment: Wait, what? How is `cursStr[whatever] - 1` a valid lvalue?

Comment: @Tinctorius It actually is a valid value, but won't do the expected... :) Many eyes and shallow bugs etc. Thanks.